# Why does BinaryWriter prepend gibberish to the start of a stream?  How do you avoid it?

Tags: c#, binarywriter, filestream, .net

I'm debugging some issues with writing pieces of an object to a file and I've gotten down to the base case of just opening the file and writing "TEST" in it.  I'm doing this by something like:

```
static FileStream fs;
static BinaryWriter w;
fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create);
w = new BinaryWriter(fs);

w.Write("test");

w.Close();
fs.Close();
```

Unfortunately, this ends up prepending a box to the front of the file and it looks like so:

TEST, with a fun box on the front.  Why is this, and how can I avoid it?

Edit: It does not seem to be displaying the box here, but it's the unicode character that looks like gibberish.

Comment: @Eric, I will be pushing the contents of many files into this file to be read later on.  However, I wish to check that the file begins with "TEST", otherwise I will not read the file.

Comment: To actually answer your question: the binary writer writes out a binary string by prepending it with the length of the string. That way the binary *reader* knows how much string data there is coming next.

Comment: If what you want to do is write the string as an array of characters, not as a string, then try doing w.Write("test".ToCharArray()); to force the writer to write out the characters as an array rather than as a length-prefixed string.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.  There is no way around this, I'd assume?  So I should check for the 2nd, third, fourth and fifth characters, rather than the first 4?

Comment: There are plenty of ways around it. You can write out a char array, you can write out a byte array, you can write out four individual bytes, you can do whatever you want. You control the format of your binary file; if you don't like the default string handling, go ahead and implement your own.

Comment: Alternatively, you could have your reader program check that the first FIVE bytes are 04 74 65 73 74.

Comment: Eric Don't tell programmers to not care. Every developer out of here CARES about format he wants to understand, be it binary or text. Chris, use the byte[] overload, not the string one, to get finest control.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

They are not byte-order marks but a length-prefix, according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yzxa6408.aspx):

```
public virtual void Write(string value);
```

> Writes a length-prefixed string to
>   [the] stream

And you will need that length-prefix if you ever want to read the string back from that point. See [`BinaryReader.ReadString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.readstring.aspx).

### Additional

Since it seems you actually want a File-Header checker

1. Is it a problem? You read the length-prefix back so as a type-check on the File it works OK
2. You can convert the string to a byte[] array, probably using Encoding.ASCII. But hen you have to either use a fixed (implied) length or... prefix it yourself. After reading the byte[] you can convert it to a string again.
3. If you had a lot of text to write you could even attach a TextWriter to the same stream. But be careful, the Writers want to close their streams. I wouldn't advice this in general, but it is good to know. Here too you will have to mark a Point where the other reader can take over (fixed header works OK).

Answer (score 8):

That's because a BinaryWriter is writing the binary representation of the string, including the length of the string. If you were to write straight data (e.g. byte[], etc.) it won't include that length.

```
byte[] text = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("test");
FileStream fs = new FileStream("C:\\test.txt", FileMode.Create);
BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(fs);
writer.Write(text);
writer.Close();
```

You'll notice that it doesn't include the length. If you're going to be writing textual data using the binary writer, you'll need to convert it first.

Answer (score 8):

The byte at the start is the length of the string, it's written out as a variable-length integer.

If the string is 127 characters or less, the length will be stored as one byte. When the string hits 128 characters, the length is written out as 2, and it will move to 3 and 4 at some lengths as well.

The problem here is that you're using BinaryWriter, which writes out data that BinaryReader can read back in later. If you wish to write out in a custom format of your own, you must either drop writing strings like that, or drop using BinaryWriter altogether.

Answer (score 7):

As Henk pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488486/why-does-binarywriter-prepend-gibberish-to-the-start-of-a-stream-how-do-you-avo/1488545#1488545), this is the length of the string (as a 32-bit int).

If you don't want this, you can either write "TEST" manually by writing the ASCII characters for each letter as bytes, or you could use:

```
System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("TEST")
```

And write the resulting array (which will NOT contain a length int)

Comment: You saved my day sir. Thank you very much!                                                                                  bw.Write(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(YourStringVariableToOutputToFile));

Answer (score 2):

What you're seeing is actually a 7 bit encoded integer, which is a kind of [integer compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_quantity).
The BinaryWriter prepend the text with this so readers (i.e. BinaryReader) will know how long the written string is.

- [BinaryWriter.Write7BitEncodedInt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.write7bitencodedint.aspx)
- [BinaryReader.Read7BitEncodedInt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.read7bitencodedint.aspx)

You can read more about the implementation details of this at http://dpatrickcaldwell.blogspot.se/2011/09/7-bit-encoding-with-binarywriter-in-net.html.

Answer (score 0):

You can save it as a UTF8 encoded byte array like this:

```
...

BinaryWriter w = new BinaryWriter(fs);

w.Write(UTF8Encoding.Default.GetBytes("test"));

...
```

Answer (score -1):

That's a byte order mark, most likely. It's because the stream's encoding is set to Unicode.

Answer (score -1):

Remember that Java strings are internally encoded in UTF-16.

So, "test" is actually made of the bytes 0xff, 0xfe (together the byte order mark), 0x74, 0x00, 0x65, 0x00, 0x73, 0x00, 0x74, 0x00.

You probably want to work with bytes instead of streams of characters.

Comment: Remember that a C# tag means: It's not Java.

Answer (score -2):

Sounds like byte order marks.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte-order_mark

Perhaps you want to write the string as UTF-8.

Comment: See Henk's response - it's a length indicator, not byte order.

Comment: So I gather.   Based on the initial information, the BOM diagnosis was quite reasonable, though.