# I cant write data to a binary file in a loop

Tags: vb.net, binaryfiles

All of my data (name/rollnumber/class) is of a fixed length (14 bytes), I want the program to keep taking a random name from the array, then make a random rollnumber and keep writing it into a file until I press "A".

After i finish running the program, the first 14 bytes are always empty and then my data is in the next 14 bytes. Nothing more nothing less. I don't know why it only wrote one data record.

This is my code:

```
    Dim randomvalue As Integer

    'Making this array so that each data entry has 14 bytes to it

    Dim array1(91) As Integer

    array1(1) = 14
    For x = 2 To 91
        array1(x) = array1(x) + 14
    Next

    Dim n1, n2, n3, n4 As Integer

    'Array with names of fixed lenght, I want to take a name from only these 9:

    Dim array2(9) As String
    array2(1) = "aleen"
    array2(2) = "talha"
    array2(3) = "waddi"
    array2(4) = "hasna"
    array2(5) = "hassa"
    array2(6) = "zainn"
    array2(7) = "faqeh"
    array2(8) = "furru"
    array2(9) = "ibrah"

  'There is a structure above submain with studentname/rollnumber/class all declared as string 

    Dim newstudent As student
    Dim studentstream As New FileStream("C:\Users\Students\Desktop\A2Filing.dat", FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
    Dim bw As New BinaryWriter(studentstream)

    While Console.ReadLine <> "A"
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key other than 'A' if you want to make another entry into the file")


        'CInt(Math.Floor((upperlimit - lowerlimit + 1) * Rnd())) + lowerlimit
        'Randomize a number b/w 1-9 to get a studentname from the array

        randomvalue = CInt(Math.Floor((9 - 1 + 1) * Rnd())) + 1
        newstudent.studentname = array2(randomvalue)

        n1 = Rnd() + (Rnd() * 50)
        n2 = Rnd() * 10
        n3 = Rnd() * 255
        n4 = Rnd() * Rnd()
        newstudent.rollnumber = Convert.ToString(Left(n1, 1) + Left(n2, 1) + Left(n3, 1) + Left(n4, 1))

        newstudent.studentclass = "A2"

        'Randomize a number between 91 and 1 to place the data in

        Dim randomvalue2 As Integer
        randomvalue2 = CInt(Math.Floor((91 - 1 + 1) * Rnd())) + 1
        studentstream.Position = array1(randomvalue2)


        bw.Write(newstudent.studentname)
        bw.Write(newstudent.rollnumber)
        bw.Write(newstudent.studentclass)
    End While
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some notes here:

- the `array1` items as you init will all be 14, you have to change it to following, but as i'll say later it is not required to define such array!

  ```
  For x = 2 To 91
    array1(x) = array1(x - 1) + 14   'modified to array1(x - 1)
  Next
  ```
- before `bw.Write`, you have this: `studentstream.Position = array1(randomvalue2)` which will override the file position! also all items in `array1` are equal to 14. this is why you get always a small file size (nothing more nothing less). you don't need to set position this way. **Just remove that line from your code** to append data one after one.
- According to documentations, if you use a `BinaryWriter` to write strings, it will be prefixed by string-length! [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1488486/2803565).

  ```
  Dim bw As New BinaryWriter(studentstream, System.Text.Encoding.ASCII)

  bw.Write("A")  'writes: 1 A  => where 1 is length of string "A"
  bw.Write("BC") 'writes: 2 B  => where 2 is length of string "BC" 

  'note that for Unicode Encoding, it will be 2 bytes per char
  Dim bw As New BinaryWriter(studentstream, System.Text.Encoding.Unicode)
  bw.Write("A")  '2 A 0        where 2 is length of unicde string [A 0]
  bw.Write("BC") '4 B 0 C 0    where 4 is length of unicde string [B 0 C 0]
  ```
- If you want to write strings without length prefix, you can use `System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str)` to convert it to byte array:

  ```
  bw.Write(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(newstudent.studentname))
  ```
- Another option will also be to use `StreamWriter` instead of `BinaryWriter` as it seems you don't need it. [see this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2404408/2803565)
- note that its better to open files with `Using` block. otherwise, do not forget to call `Close` method (`studentstream.Close()`) when you finished. if you don't do this, you may lose last chunk or whole of your data!

  ```
  Using studentstream As New FileStream("C:\...\Desktop\A2Filing.dat", FileMode.Create)
  ```
- use `FileMode.Create` to override the file if it already exists

Comment: thank you! It worked, I decided to keep this     studentstream.Position = array1(randomvalue2) because I didnt want to append data to the file, i want to put it in a random place (made a overflow thingy too: a while loop that keeps adding +1 to the studentstream.position until it encounters a empty space)