# Java - Write a string prefixed with the 7 bit encoded length

Tags: java, c#, serialization, stream, binarywriter

I am trying to recreate C#'s BinaryWriter's Write function on a string in Java.
The C# method writes a string's length encoded in 7-bit format, and then the string. Is there any way I can implement this in Java?
I've tried implementing it like so, to no success:

```
long v = value & 0x00000000ffffffffL;
while (v >= 0x80) {
  writeByte((byte) (v | 0x80));
  v >>= 7;
}
writeByte((byte) v);
```

Comment: Do you have any reference to this 7-bit encoded format? If I lookup BinaryWriter.write it is only mentioned that the length is written as an unsigned integer, no mention of this 7-bit encoded format. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yzxa6408(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: In BinaryWriter.Write's source, the method Write7BitEncodedInt is called on the string length. http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/binarywriter.cs,2daa1d14ff1877bd

Comment: That's clear. Surprised that his is not mentioned in the documentation. What is the problem with your above code; in what way does the output differ from the same function in C# ?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt, I tried writing two strings, one with my Java implementation and one with the C# implementation. The C# string is slightly different, it has an odd symbol at the end.

Comment: I tried your code and it works like I would expect it to. Can you post a hex dump (only of the encoded length portion) of a case where you have a difference between Java and C#?

Comment: http://pastie.org/pastes/10236918/text

Comment: I dont have time to poke at this but I am going to bet that your getting different values because C#'s `byte` is unsigned where as Java's is not, I think if you change `byte` to `sbyte` on the C# code you will at least get the same output (correct or not).

Comment: @lanour what data were you writing there? the data starts with a 00 (zero) byte which shouldn't be possible unless the length was zero.

Comment: See implementation in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12889458/) on the duplicate question.