# BinaryWriter puts dirty chars at the begin writing in AppendMode

Tags: c#, .net, file-io, binarywriter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does BinaryWriter prepend gibberish to the start of a stream? How do you avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488486/why-does-binarywriter-prepend-gibberish-to-the-start-of-a-stream-how-do-you-avo)

The issue occurs during the execution of a NTService which writes many reports on a file. This is the simple code I used:

```
 FileStream fsw = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write);
            BinaryWriter w = new BinaryWriter(fsw);
            w.Write(report);
            w.Flush();
            fsw.Flush();
            w.Close();
            fsw.Close();
```

The output is properly flushed in the file, but at the begin of every write two strange character appears (ï¿½). I deploy the service on several machines and the problem persist.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use BinaryWriter?Maybe you should write text in a text file instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    BinaryWriter w = new BinaryWriter(fsw);

    w.Write(UTF8Encoding.Default.GetBytes(report));
```

Comment: Thanks! This tip fix the problem for me!