# Streamwriter adding characters to first line

Tags: c#, .net, streamwriter

I am doing something rather simple in c#, writing a list of strings to text file. My write sub is:

```
public static bool TextToFile(string fileName, List<string> inString) {
    if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName)))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName));
    try {
        if (File.Exists(fileName))
            File.Delete(fileName);

        const int BufferSize = 65536;  // 64 Kilobytes
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileName, true, Encoding.UTF8, BufferSize)) {
            if (inString.Count > 0) {
                foreach (string str in inString) {
                    sw.WriteLine(str);
                }
            }
            else
                sw.WriteLine("");
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I am getting extra stuff at the beginning of the first line though.
It does not show in a regular text editor, but when I opened in ultraedit, and went to hex mode, I saw this:
[image]

My programs that read the text file do see the characters, and confuse it.
My list of strings is super clean.
I am sometimes writing 100 mb text files, so am setting the buffer to 64k, but I tried leaving it as default with same results.
I am on win7 64 bit, using VS 2013.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: I just noticed that if I save the resulting text file as ansi encoding, that wierd text goes away. Then I tried saving back to utf-8, and it came back. Is this proper behavior? I never want hidden characters in a text file...

Comment: indeed, its the BOM. Should I leave it there or not?

Comment: I see, like this: New StreamWriter("Foobar.txt", False, utf8WithoutBom)
several other posts on this once you know the keywords....thx

Comment: It does not seem to be the cause, but might be related: length-prefixed strings (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488486/why-does-binarywriter-prepend-gibberish-to-the-start-of-a-stream-how-do-you-avo)

Comment: To control UTF-8 file saving with or without BOM in UltraEdit, read UE forum answer [What's the best default new file format?](https://www.ultraedit.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=15438#p52594) UltraEdit indicates detected encoding of text file in status bar at bottom of UE main window for active file.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem and (thanks to the comments on this question) identified these characters as the [Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)
Which then allowed me to change the encoding to exclude the BOM using this code:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileName, true, new UTF8Encoding(false), BufferSize))
```